# Emacs Windows - capslock doesn't enable uppercase typing

Tags: windows, emacs, capslock

I have Emacs 24.1.1 for Windows. When I turn on the capslock key, Emacs doesn't enable uppercase typing. Capslock works in the rest of windows, and in my ssh'd terminals. I haven't done anything to modify the capslock key. `w32-capslock-is-shiftlock` is `nil`. `w32-enable-caps-lock` is `t`.

Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug - which version of Windows are you using? Have you tried starting Emacs with the `-q` flag?

Comment: This seems to have stopped happening. Strange. All's well for now.